# Reading line by line with python's Pandas after skipping first 48 rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv, line-by-line

The title is fairly explanatory.

I have a long CSV file that I would like to read line by line with the following code:

```
lines = []
for line in pd.read_csv(file, chunksize = 1, header = None):
    lines.append(line.iloc[0 0])
print(lines)
```

I'd like to skip the first 48 rows. At first it seemed simple enough and I thought all I needed to do was change my read function to:

```
pd.read_csv(file,chunksize = 1, header = None, skiprows = 48):
```

Sadly, this seems to produce the effect of skipping 48 rows every single loops. Not a great outcome.

How can I read line by line which is effectively reading this file while simultaneously skipping the first 48 rows of this long, irregular file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set skiprows to a variable that gets reset after its first execution.

```
lines = []
row_skip = 48
for line in pd.read_csv(file, chunksize = 1, header = None,skiprows=row_skip):
    lines.append(line.iloc[0,0])
    if row_skip:
        row_skip = None
print(lines)
```

Comment: Excellent! That helped me so much with the issue I brought to hand. I now have some further problems ahead of me, but thank you so much for the assistance!